# Many To Many friendlist with symfony 3

Tags: doctrine-orm, many-to-many, symfony-3.1

I want to make a friendlist using ManyToMany self-referencing. 
I followed [this link](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing) and it seemms to be good. But Now, what Action should I have in my controller to : 
1- get All myFriends / or all all friend of current user
2- add a firend, using a link such as "Add friend"

thank you for your time and answers

Answer (score 0):

in your link my friends is a doctrine array collection, to get the friends of a user just iterate on it and to add a friend just add a friend onto this collection and save the entity (with the entity manager), maybe you ll need to add a cascade persist on the collection to add a new user as friend.

you have to add some methods like getMyFriends, addFriend and removeFriend

```
<?php
/** @Entity */
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Many Users have Many Users.
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="myFriends")
     */
    private $friendsWithMe;

    /**
     * Many Users have many Users.
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friendsWithMe")
     * @JoinTable(name="friends",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $myFriends;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->friendsWithMe = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->myFriends = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getMyFriends(){
        return $this->myFriends;
    }

    public function addFriend(User $friend){
        $this->myFriends->add($friend);
    }

    public function removeFriend(User $friend){
        $this->myFriends->removeElement($friend);
    }
}
```

in your controller you have to implement an action with

```
$currentUser= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
$myFriends = $currentUser->getMyfriends();
$this->render('your-template.html.twig', array(
    'myFriends' => $myFriends,
));
```

and in your twig template

```
<h1>My friends</h1>
<ul>
    {% for friend in myFriends %}
        <li>{{ friend.username }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: In my database, I have a new table which contains user_id and friend_user_id . But I dont have an entity named "friend" in my source code.

Comment: it's a self-referencing relationship you haven't a friend entity it's user but now in your user entity you have a fields friends which is a collection of users

Comment: is it ok for you ?

Comment: Thank you Francois, but not yet...
In my controller I can return an array containg all users, but I didnt found how to get only "myFriends" . 
in my Twig I wrote : 
{% for friend in friends %}
  {{ friend.myFriends }}

Comment: read the code i have posted :
public function getMyFriends(){
        return $this->myFriends;
}
myFriends is a private field you have to implement a getter

Comment: Does it matter to which field we add JoinColumn annotation? (Would be ok to add it to $friendsWithMe instead of $myFriends?)